# MP Movie Player Controller orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app i need to restrict portrait view for MP movie player. i want to know how can i override  shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation function in MP movie player.m file or is it possible?

Comment: Are you referring to MPMoviePlayerController or to MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Comment: i have used MPMoviePlayerController only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation return YES only for the Portrait orientation.